# vagrant cannot access webserver on localhost:8080

Tags: centos, vagrant

I am running CentOS 6.4 through vagrant.

I have put this line inside my Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
```

Then I have installed nginx in the VM and verified it's working with:

```
wget http://locahost/
```

Works fine.

But from my host machine (Macbook Air, Mountain Lion) when I go to:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

It times out. Did I miss any configuration in Vagrantfile?

I have used this box:

https://github.com/NREL/vagrant-boxes

Comment: Sounds ok, maybe there is some kind of firewall involved?

Answer (score 9):

Have you checked your iptables?

It's a common mistake: when you use provisioning you also have to configure your iptables. (For puppet you have [this module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/bobsh/iptables).) If you don't want to work with a firewall you can just do `vagrant ssh` followed by `sudo service iptables stop`.

Answer (score 1):

What do you see when you go to your browser? Does it say `Data not received` or it never stops reloading? Do you get any messages in your browser? The server config file must be a bit messed up. Try reloading the server configuration, and restarting it.

Also, try changing the port number to something else. With the newer version of Vagrant, the syntex looks a bit different.  So you have to do:

`config.vm.forward_port 80, 2759`

This is the config file that I use for one of my instances:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.box       = 'rails-dev-ready'
  config.vm.host_name = 'rails-dev-ready'

  config.vm.forward_port 5800, 5800
  config.vm.forward_port 1080, 1090
  config.vm.forward_port 80, 2759

  config.vm.provision :puppet,
    :manifests_path => 'puppet/manifests',
    :module_path    => 'puppet/modules'
config.vm.share_folder "sharedapps", "/home/vagrant/sharedapps", "sharedapps"

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently set up a CentOS 6.4 box. My ports got all messed up because of `iptables`. I just disabled the service. It's in `/sbin/sevices`.

Answer (score 0):

You may run the following command to find out if any other process (such as Tomcat) is bind to port 8080:

```
lsof -i :8080
```

If so, that may cause the problem.

Comment: I had to run this command as `sudo` in order to get everything.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution,

I have found that there is an issue with Apache + vagrant, and sometimes Apache won't start automatically.

Please try: `sudo service apache2 start` once logged in via ssh.

I was having issues with Vagrant and all the error messages indicated a networking problem, but in reality my Apache service just wasn't starting on `vagrant up`